# how to turn off version number in eclipse juno?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno

how to turn off the version numbers in the folders when checking out projects in eclipse juno?
So in package explorer the version numbers are showing up....

`com.myco.action.MyAbstractAction 2`

`com.myco.action.MyUtilityClass 3`

`.....`

`.....`

`com.myco.service.ItemService 7`

It seems the directory version # is coming up.  How do I turn this off.....

Comment: what do you check out, are you using a plug-in for a Version Control System like SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearances -> Label Decorations

Uncheck your Version-Control-System